# Coverage.py warning: No data was collected -- files needs to be in the same directory

Tags: python, unit-testing, python-unittest

When I run Python unit-test in LiClipse I get this error: `Coverage.py warning: No data was collected`.

My directory structure looks like this:

```
datafunnel >> src >> src_files.py
datafunnel >> test >> test_files.py
```

My `.coveragerc` file looks like this:

```
[path]
source = C:\Users\sepham\"My Documents"\"LiClipse Workspace"\sengtool_data_funnel\datafunnel\
```

When I run the Python unit test, I get the error message as stated in the title and I get no numbers for the Coverage %.

However, if I put the `test_files.py` in the same directory as the `src_files.py`, then the tests work nicely. I'm not sure what I need to do to fix this directory business.